# jasmine matcher functions not loading in angularjs/karma unit tests

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, jasmine, bower, karma-jasmine

I'm writing unit tests for an angularJs app, I'm using the karma test runner with the jasmine framework.

I'm testing a function that should pull objects from firebase, I've installed the `jasmine-expect` with `karma-jasmine-matchers` plugin.

My function is as follows:

```
describe('Controller: QuizCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('geafApp'));

  var QuizCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    QuizCtrl = $controller('QuizCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should contain answers object from firebase', function () {
    expect(scope.questions).toBeNonEmptyObject();
  });
  });
```

I then run:

> grunt karma

to run the tests, but it fails with the following error:

> ```
>     TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'expect(scope.questions).toBeNonEmptyObject()')
> ```

My package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "geaf",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "German Embassy Quiz",
  "dependencies": {},
  "repository": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.1",
    "chalk": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.1.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.12.0",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-bower": "0.0.10",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "http-server": "^0.6.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "jasmine-expect": "^1.22.3",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-jasmine-matchers": "^2.0.0-beta1",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.3.3",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-ng-scenario": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.1.0",
    "protractor": "~0.20.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.2.6",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "karma start karma.conf.js  --single-run",
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor-conf.js",
    "update-index-async": "node -e \"require('shelljs/global'); sed('-i', /\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/, '//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n' + cat('app/bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js') + '\\n//@@NG_LOADER_END@@', 'app/index-async.html');\""
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

My karma.conf.js loads the plugins as follows:

plugins: [
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-firefox-launcher',
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-junit-reporter',
  'karma-jasmine-matchers'
],

I've ran both `npm install` and `bower install` so the functions should load up correctly but seem not to.

Any help is greatly appreciated as it's my first time writing angular apps and unit tests for them.

Comment: Have you added `jasmine-matchers` as a framework to *karma.conf.js* like [here](https://github.com/JamieMason/karma-jasmine-matchers-example/blob/master/karma.conf.js#L11)?

Comment: thanks thats what i was missing, add this to an answer so i can accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to add `jasmine-matchers` as a framework to *karma.conf.js*:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    // ...
    frameworks: [
        'jasmine',
        'jasmine-matchers' // here
    ],

    plugins: [
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-firefox-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
        'karma-junit-reporter',
        'karma-jasmine-matchers'
    ]
    // ....
};
```

[Here](https://github.com/JamieMason/karma-jasmine-matchers-example/blob/master/karma.conf.js#L11) is a reference to official Karma config sample for *jasmine-matchers*.

Also, if you don't have any plugins, then it would be enough just to specify a framework.

Comment: thanks for this answer, here is also a working example for anyone that might need it https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers/tree/master/examples/karma